# Find a selector starting with a letter

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'd like to find a CSS selector or selectors starting with a given letter. Is this possible?

```
.myClass[id^=' ... ']
```

(`...` represents any letter)

Comment: Any letter = Any alphabet?

Comment: for reference http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

Comment: @Harry Sorry for my English, ANY alphabet

Comment: this is not possible in just 1 selector.

Comment: @DoXicK I think you are right, I read all the documentation also and couldnt find that way. I guess I just close the question.

Comment: Well why a selector to match any alphabet? If I am not wrong, CSS will not allow id/class to start with a numeric.

Comment: @BadrHari `.myClass[id^=a],.myClass[id^=b],.myClass[id^=c]` ;-)

Comment: @Harry correct. However, people still do it :-(

Comment: @Harry, in HTML5 it is valid. [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) vs [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

Comment: @DoXicK The whole thing is such a mess (the reason I ask such stupid question is proof) that I might as well do it haha

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra thanks ^_^ learned something new today ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pre-defined css selector for this. You can use the `filter` method:

```
$('.myClass[id]').filter(function() {
    return /[A-Za-z]/.test(this.id[0]);
});
```

You can also define a pseudo-selector:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], { 
    youNameIt: function(a) { 
        return /[A-Za-z]/.test(a.id[0]);
    }    
}); 

$('.myClass:youNameIt');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can try this

element[att^=val]

Please see http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/ Link for reference